# In Google Analytics, is it possible to display Total Screens Viewed with # of users each?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

In Google Analytics, how would I be able to display total screens viewed (Total of Screen Depths per User) for a time period with # of users? (Mobile Application)

Currently I am able to display total screens viewed per session with (1) sessions and (2) unique users.

However, I need screen depth in total.

Example:

```
 Total Screen Depth For Time Period    |     # of Users

          1                                      200
          2                                      500
          3                                      300
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is segments and creating segments with different ranges for different # of users.